# Reduce cron log level with systemd

Tags: systemd, journald

Googling for a solution, I only found articles telling me how to do it in old systems and not under a systemd maintained Linux, by changing the cron init-script adding -L parameter to the command line.

I have a cron job that runs every minute. It logs every start and additionall a pam_unix-entry for each session opened and closed for the user running cron. This is a lot of babbeling in the journald log. How can I set the log level in a systemd-environment, that I only get errors and fatalities documented?

Example messages:

```
CRON[4041958]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
CRON[4041958]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: Which distro are you using ?

Comment: Debian atm, but same goes for Ubuntu and Arch

Comment: Ubuntu changed to systemd between 14.04 and 16.04 - yet the 16.04 version still has the 14.04-type files there with `exec cron` and uses them WHEN IT HAS BEEN UPGRADED FROM AN ORIGINAL 14.04 INSTALL.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281117/cron-pam-unixcronsession-session-opened-for-user-root-by-uid-0-is-it-a-m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so I only have EL systems to hand but I asked a friend who as a Debian 8 system and the answer is broadly the same.

For Debian using cron (substitute crond for EL)

```
systemctl status cron 
systemctl status cron
cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2015-11-02 21:13:22 CET; 1 months 0 days ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 983 (cron)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           983 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

If you then look at the contents of `/lib/systemd/system/cron.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Regular background program processing daemon
Documentation=man:cron(8)

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/cron
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -f $EXTRA_OPTS
IgnoreSIGPIPE=false
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You can see that it loads an environment file `/etc/default/cron` amd from that file it uses `$EXTRA_OPTS`

If your cron daemon supports it you can provide an option to change the logging verbosity there

```
EXTRA_OPTS="-L 0"
```

The man page for your distro's cron(d)(8) should tell you what logging options you have.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

For the same in Fedora, follow @Iain’s instructions but edit the `CRONDARGS` option in `/etc/sysconfig/crond` instead.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu I set to override ExecStart parameter via `systemctl edit cron` as follows:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -L 0 -f $EXTRA_OPTS
```

Where `-L 0` disables logging.

Answer (score 0):

`-L 0` does not help on Debian 12 because the messages are not generated by cron, but by PAM.

See this debian bug report for details: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=293272

Answer (score 0):

Actually this the sole reason for this chatty logging is **PAM** configuration. To make it less noisy:

- Go to the `/etc/pam.d` directory.
- Open the file common-session-noninteractive in an editor.
- Look for the following line:

  `session required        pam_unix.so`
- Above this line, add the following:

  `session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in cron quiet use_uid`
- Save the file and exit.
  Restart crond using something like service cron restart.

Solution described here: https://languor.us/cron-pam-unix-cron-session-session-opened-closed-user-root-uid0
and here: https://askubuntu.com/a/280255/366528

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/572415)